# Dragging to fire UIButtons

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, user-interface

I have four UIButtons on a UIView in an iPad application being developed at the moment for iPad Simulator 3.2.

What currently happens is this: The user drags their finger from one button to another. As the finger leaves the first button, that button remains in its active state, and nothing happens as the finger passes over the second button unless the user releases the touch and taps the screen again on the second button.

What I need to happen is, the moment their finger leaves the area of the first UIButton, it should go back to its default UI state, and when the finger enters the area of the second UIButton, the second button should assume its active state, and fire an event.

I'm really completely lost as to how to accomplish this, I've done lots of Googling, nothing has offered a quick solution to what seems to me like something that should be easy to accomplish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look into modifying the actions for your button to use [one of the many different control events available](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events). Namely, this sounds like you need to register your buttons to perform actions on UIControlEventTouchDragEnter and/or UIControlEventTouchDragExit.

Comment: I'm already using those, the main problem is that when the finger leaves a button (TouchDragExit), it no longer fires TouchDragEnters for other buttons it passes over, it only fires when the finger goes back over the initial button. TouchDragEnter also doesn't fire when dragging from the background UIView to a button.

Comment: It definitely sounds hairy to get working right. Perhaps you'd be better off manually tracking the touch events? You were able to describe the logic and conditions of the desired action very succinctly. It would probably be similarly straightforward, though perhaps not necessarily easy, to track the state of the touch (as it touches down/up and enters/exits regions) and figure out the appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use UIButtons here.  Instead create your own view, and do touch handling yourself.  You can easily track the X and Y position of any view inside your custom view and respond accordingly.

UIButtons just are not designed for this kind of use.